# Issues with adjacent fragments in a ViewPager which contributes to Activity that holds it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

When adjacent [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) in a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) contributes to the activity(OptionsMenu or View) , the contents from the adjacent fragments get loaded even before the actual page has been selected.

This issue has been discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/_opT-Lr_hgE) and [reported](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19203) by Jake Wharton some months ago.
Is this issue fixed in the latest release of [compatibilty library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)?

Comment: This isn't an issue... adjacent fragments get loaded to ensure that the fragment's content is visible as you swipe.

Comment: so what if those pages contribute to options menu or the activity's layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`setMenuVisibility(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.html#setMenuVisibility%28android.app.Fragment,%20boolean%29) on the adjacent `Fragment`s, and then implement an `OnPageChangedListener` that sets `setMenuVisibility(true)` when the page is shown.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this [patch](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=19203&aid=192030001000&name=Issue19203.patch&token=oqTK2-_FHddGMZ-E7ZHKS2wsKNM:1344929219410)

This issue has been fixed in the latest releases.